# Formula for updated currency exchange rates in Excel or other spreadsheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-docs, worksheet-function

What kind of spreadsheets support a formula like the following:

```
=exchangeCurrency("USD"; "EUR"; 3000)
```

The result should be 3000 USD exchanged into Euros. Possibly a date could be provided for a historic exchange rate. Alternatively, the average for the last month or so.

I would use such a feature all the time and it has to be relevant for so many other users. I prefer working in Excel, but online spreadsheets like Google or Zoho is also fine.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

In Google Spreadsheets, getting current exchange rates is very easy with the built-in Google Finance querying function. E.g, to get the current rate for USD/EUR:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:USDEUR")
```

This will work for all exchange rates Google Finance is tracking. See https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/11/30/currency-conversion-google-sheets/ for more examples.

Comment: FYI: Link no longer works, as the site has been removed

Comment: Thanks @Chef1075 - I've replaced the link with one that works.

Answer (score 29):

Here are some options for you:

#### GOOGLE SPREADSHEETS

There's a Google Spreadsheet script that returns the exchange rate between EURO and a currency that you specify. Data is supposedly from the European Central Bank.

**Setup:**

Open a Google Docs Spreadsheet.

Click **Insert** > **Script** > Search for ECBExchangeRate

Install it.

**Usage:**

```
=ECBExchangeRate("mm.dd.yyyy", "USD")
```

** With quotes on the date

This will return the exchange rate between USD and EUR for the date mm/dd/yyyy. Unfortunately, the data source isn't updated.

**Calculating between 2 Currencies:**

For example, we want to get the USD/JPY rate for today. Get EUR/USD and EUR/JPY using the formula above. Divide the EUR/JPY rate by the EUR/USD rate. You get USD/JPY.

#### EXCEL

I don't believe such a function exists for Excel (at least by default). You can, however, set up a sheet that imports data from an online exchange rate table like the one on the Yahoo Finance page (finance.yahoo.com > Investing > Currencies > Currencies Investing > Cross Rates).

You can then setup a VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH formula to get the relevant exchange rates for you.

**Setup:**

Create a new sheet (recommended).

Click **Data** > **From Web** > Enter the following URL:

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-investing#cross-rates
```

Click the yellow arrow beside the exchange rate table. The arrow should turn into a green check mark. Click **Import**.

Click **Properties**. Under **Refresh Control**, specify how often you want Excel to retrieve new data, or pick **Refresh data when opening the file.** Click OK then wait for Excel to load the data.

To refresh the data, just hit **Ctrl-Alt-F5**.

Here's a sample spreadsheet:[image]

The data on the Yahoo Finance Page is pretty limited, but it covers the most popular currencies. You can use other sources, such as:

```
http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html
```

The website http://www.xe.com/ucc/ has historical rate tables which you can consolidate.

Comment: [Menu option Insert -> Script… is missing in the new Google Sheets](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67078/menu-option-insert-script-is-missing-in-my-spreadsheet-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 6):

**Google Spreadsheets:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20716922/462347

**Microsoft Excel:**

- Download data in CSV format from Yahoo Finances and import it to Excel as a query.

**How to import the data from Yahoo Finances to Excel?**

1. Go to *Data → From Web*.
2. Specify the data URL in the field `URL`, e.g. for the USD to EUR rate:
   http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDEUR=X&f=b
3. Press *Load*. The new sheet with the required data will be automatically created.
4. You can hide the header and the style of the cell by unselecting the *Header Row* and *Banded Rows* respectively.

That's all, now you have a cell with the desired data. You can referece to the cell like to any other cell in Excel.

**Good to know:**

- You can manually trigger the data refresh by clicking on *Data → Refresh All*. For automatic update when a workbook is opened: https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Refresh-an-external-data-connection-in-Excel-2016-for-Windows-1524175f-777a-48fc-8fc7-c8514b984440
- The URL in the example above contains the `&f=b` fragment, which means bid. For the detailed Yahoo Finances query data parameters, please see: http://www.financialwisdomforum.org/gummy-stuff/Yahoo-data.htm

Comment: Sadly, download.finance.yahoo.com doesn't seem to be valid anymore. Has anybody found any current alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

This Excel spreadsheet connects to a web service (Oanda) to automatically download historical exchange rates.

http://investexcel.net/222/automatically-download-historical-forex-data-into-excel/

The VBA is exposed, so you can hack away at the code I wrote. You should be able to create a function like

```
=exchangeCurrency("USD"; "EUR"; 3000)
```

which uses an 30-day average exchange rate or something.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the plugin below for quite some time. Works great for me. It uses Yahoo API and MSN money website to get live currency rates in Excel exposed as custom functions. i.e. =Fx_Convert(100,"USD","EUR")

http://technitya.com/content/Live-Currency-in-Excel

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?rd=1) function which fetches current or historical securities information from Google Finance. You can use it with the following syntax:

```
GOOGLEFINANCE(ticker, [attribute], [start_date], [end_date|num_days], [interval])
```

Sample usages:

```
=GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD")
=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "marketcap", DATE(2012,1,1), DATE(2012,12,31), "DAILY")
=Index(GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD", "close", DATE(year($A1), month($A1), day($A1)), DATE(year($A1), month($A38), day($A38)+1), "DAILY"), 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Excel UDF that scrapes exchange rate data from Yahoo Finance [here](http://investexcel.net/3590/foreign-exchange-rate-function-in-excel/)

This is the syntax

```
=FXRate("currency1", "currency2",["close", "open", "bid", "ask"])
```

So to convert 30 GBP to USD, you'd write

```
=30*FXRate("GBP", "USD","bid")
```

I think that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Spearian for MS Excel, http://spearianforexcel.com, to work and to download all history of any exchange rate. It's very comfortable for obtaining access to all major market data, including Yahoo Finance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a free currency conversion tool available for excel which converts between over 160 currencies. The pro version can also use historical data:

http://www.office-plugins.net/free-excel-currency-converter/

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft finally added the support for live currency rates and stocks to Office 365. Now you can use MS Excel, if you get used to it. Here is how:

1. Enter currency pair into the cell into whatever format: USD/AED, ASD:AED, ASDAED
2. Select this cell, go to Data ribbon and find Stock icon
3. Press Stock icon and wait while Excel recognizes your pair and fetches currency data
4. The press the datepicker to the right and select Price

Voila! The rate will appear in the cell to the right

[image]

**Note**: the Stock function is only be available in subscription versions of Office 365
for Microsoft 365 accounts (Worldwide Multi-Tenant clients), it is not available to Excel 2019 Desktop version.

Answer (score -1):

You won't find anything built in to any spreadsheet for something which changes constantly like exchange rates.  Thankfully, there are solutions out there already that others have created for this kind of thing, such as [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Currency-Converter-With-Microsoft-Excel), [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080321185616AAbkcn8), [OzGrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/Services/excel-exchange-rates.htm), [EHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_2238845_create-currency-converter-microsoft-excel.html).

There are many other solutions, but most of them follow the same general design patterns.  If none of the above links are what you're looking for, I would suggest searching on the OzGrid site.  Their forums are often one of the best for finding Excel solutions.

Comment: None of the links are helpful. I would still be better off copying and pasting in the updated currency rate. There has to be a better solution.